# Prevent Windows 7 from booting in Safe Mode

Tags: windows-7, boot, safe-mode

I've found myself in quite the unusual situation, through my own thoughtlessness. Using a computer of which I do not have an (or *the*) administrative account on, went to msconfig, to 'boot' and selected the option to force the computer to launch in safe-mode.

Now, as of restarting the computer, it launches in safe-mode though I am then requested to log in, before I can return to the dialogue and deselect the safe-mode option. However, as I explained, this is not quite possible.

Are there any buttons I can press when the computer is launching that will give me an option to return to standard booting? I am not to use any methods such as using a restore point, restoring to factory default, deleting the administrator's account, create a new administrator account, change the password, etc. etc. - I am simply wondering if there is a method to achieve a standard boot-up, probably using an F1-12 key, and what it would be.

Many features on my environment have been disabled, so even if an answer is proposed there is a chance I will be unable to use it. Therefore, the more alternatives the better, granted they do not violate the above examples.

Using - Windows 7, Acer Travelmate B113.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit BCD after booting the system in WinRE **(Windows Recovery Environment)**

```
bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safeboot
```

Instructions on how to access Recovery Options in Windows 7 can be found [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/what-are-system-recovery-options#what-are-system-recovery-options=windows-7)